# Can you release an iOS app with a pre-populated sql db

Tags: ios, sql

I'm trying to load an sql database full of assets for my app to use upon release.

As I understand it, you can save the database to the `applicationDocumentsDirectory`:

> NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
>   URLByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASEFILENAME];

But that gets saved locally on the simulator or the test device so I'd need to keep the source assets and release them with my app to generate that sql database.

I could release the app with the assets, populate the db on first run and delete the assets. Is there anyway to just include my pre-populated DB?

Comment: How will you do the same for images ? Likewise add that populated db file to bundle and use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Simply copy the generated DB from your simulator Documents/ folder (file will have .sqlite extension) and put it in your project - making sure to add it to the package...

Comment: I feel kind of stupid for not thinking it would be that easy. Thanks friend.

Comment: Sure, please add a comment here if you face more issues. I'll be back in the evening and can help more with coding issues related to this if any. Also, if this helped, could you please mark it as an answer?

Comment: I had to wait. You answered too fast!

Answer (score 0):

Yes , certainly there's a good way. Please see my answer in the link below. I have written with explanation and sample code. Hope that will help you.

[Reading an already made sqlite file on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362453/reading-an-already-made-sqlite-file-on-ios/19364050#19364050)